# Launching a 32bit exe via OLE dispatch from a 64 bit exe

Tags: wpf, dll, com, mfc, ole

I have a WPF application compiled to ANYCPU target Platform. This application needs to launch a 32 bit MFC application. I am doing this through a COM Callable wrapper. The COM Callable wrapper launches the exe using OLE DISPATCH. If I compile COM Wrapper in win32 and launch WPF Application in x86 target platform, 32 bit legacy application launches successfully.

If I compile COM Wrapper x64 bit, and compile WPF x86, my WPF application crashes on creating object of COM Wrapper.

If I compile COM Wrapper win32 and WPF platform target ANYCPU, again my WPF application crashes. How do I setup this properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use COM targeting the same platform bit size are your current executable.  If you're running as a 32bit process, you *must* use a 32bit COM Wrapper.  If you're running as a 64bit process, you *must* use a 64bit COM wrapper.  This typically means you would need two separate builds of your application, so you could target the appropriate wrappers.

That being said, if your only goal is to launch the application (and not interact with it), you could use `Process.Start` instead of a COM wrapper to launch it.

Comment: My WPF application Platform and target platform needs to be ANYCPU. This is a must. So this means I need to compile COM ANYCPU too?

I can not use Process.Start since I definitely need to do lots of interaction between the applications.